# OS X PHP version command line

Tags: php, terminal, bin

I've got installed php 7.1.0 and 5.6.27 on my OS X. On setup it seems like I've failed.

Using php -v returns 7.1.0.
But when I navigate to /usr/local/bin/ there are two php bins

```
php
php-cli
```

Executing both -v returns 5.6.27. When I use which php I get of course:

```
/usr/local/bin/php
```

How would I need to place php7 (and how to get the bin?) so I can use for example php7 on terminal to execute PHP7 scripts?

Comment: This path doesn't exist for me.

Comment: If you do `ls -l /usr/local/bin/php`, does it point to any other file? And where is php7 installed? You can try `whereis php7`

Comment: The php version in your /usr/local/bin comes probably from custom installation from source tarball. Usual package installations usually put it into /usr/bin. The command `which php` gives only the first hit, try `whereis php` or `whereis php7` to find other locations in your path.